# rufus scheduler exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rule-engine, rufus-scheduler

This is driving me a bit nuts, I have rufus doing some scheduling to call a rules engine (ruleby). So most work I have running is inside the  running engine and then inside the scheduler. As a result when I have a error the information is a bit limited.

Fast forward, Im still working on my code but now I have this exception error:

```
'undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass'
```

It wasnt happening before, Im not sure exactly when it started and if it was what I was doing with the code or some events that came in that come in via http push. I comment out the code I think is causing it, stops happening, I put the code back in, still not happening, I leave it for a while, starts happening again. I try and run the engine manually outside the scheduler (so just once instead of every x many minutes), doesnt happen.

Put it back on the scheduler to run a few times, starts happening again. I would google the above error but google doesnt love the + in the search. Anyone have any ideas where to direct me to for this? Its clearly something happening when the rules engine is running but it was more than happily running for weeks before i got back to trying to finish it off. Best thought is that its during the rules engine running it passes events into it one at a time and something is missing that wasnt before.

Really want to know what the + method it refers to is/could be/suppose to be.

Comment: Just to add some information, Ive tried reducing the amount of information I am using and still get the same error. I have the rules engine pegged as the issue as it happens without the scheduler... but without the scheduler I dont get the exception details of course so I can see it fell over and restarted I just dont see the error.

Comment: If you could show the piece of code where the error occurs and paste the accompanying error backtrace, that'd really help people help you. Also indicating the platform (windows, osx, linux, ...), and the Ruby version and the versions of the gems you're using would help tremendously.